# Angular ui-router load specific view before resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I know it sounds counter-intuitive, but please hear my situation out. I have a "topbar" view and a "main" view. The topbar has no specific data associated with any one particular view, but it can change depending on the user's login status. This really helps to keep that part of my website robust, however it comes at a terrible cost: When I want to use "resolve", the topbar goes completely missing.  I understand the logic behind this, but I am wondering if there is anyway to target which view to actually block with resolve?

If I could only block my "main" view, but allow my "topbar" view to render, then that would be perfect. I also don't want to avoid using resolve to avoid the main view flashing nonsense when the view is first loaded.

What my routes look like:

```
$stateProvider..state("about", {
        url: "/about",
        views: {
            "topbar": {
                templateUrl: "/app/templates/topnav.html"
            },
            "main": {
                templateUrl: "/app/home/about.html",
                controller: ["$rootScope", function ($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.pageTitle = "About";
                }]
            }
        }
    }).state("courses", {
        url: "/courses",
        views: {
            "topbar": {
                templateUrl: "/app/templates/topnav-loggedin.html"
            },
            "main": {
                templateUrl: "/app/courses/courses.html",
                controller: "coursesController"
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            currentCourse: ["$http", function($http) {
                 // load course
            }]
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've made `topbar` a child state of `main`. Don't do that, make them siblings (or distant relatives)

Comment: Is it possible to share your configuration of your ui-router?

Comment: It looks like your current implementation changes the navbar when a loggedin user goes to an anonymous page - is this the behavior you want? It may be better to not use a ui-view for "topbar" and instead put it in a directive or ng-include and have it control which template is used based on whether the user is currently logged in. I think this would also prevent it from disappearing during state transitions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably make a parent, abstract state for all states requiring the *logged-in* topbar template. For example

```
.state('loggedin', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        topbar: {
            templateUrl: '/app/templates/topnav-loggedin.html'
        }
    }
}).state('courses', {
    parent: 'loggedin', // or name the state 'loggedin.courses'
    url: '/courses',
    views: {
        'main@': { // the "main" view in the root state
            templateUrl: '/app/courses/courses.html',
            controller: 'coursesController'
        }
    },
    resolve: { ... }
});
```